# Eclipse: Other tab(to find C/C++) not showing up

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a mac with Xcode and eclipse luna. I had another question saying that my mac could not program Xcode(with C++, not this question), so I turned to eclipse. Eclipse luna programs well with java... but I am interested in C++. So I look at a tutorial on how to include the C++ library with a project. I found that you must go to **New** --> **Other...** But there is no other. Then I look if the other tab does not show up tutorial and they said you must go t the top left of the screen and select C/C++, witch doesn't show ether. How can I make those tabs show up?

Comment: Oh wait before my question gets put on hold, plea read this message: Post a comment on why it is on hold and I will attempt to prove it wrong, that is if your reason is "not applicable". If it is "applicable" I will fix it. But tree got to be a phone call if not. #angry person (I wont be that mad but give me a good reason).

Comment: could you reference that other question you had? A link to it maybe

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **[CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)**  (C/C++ Development Tooling) to your Eclipse.

It was compatible with Kepler, but the Luna CDT edition (8.4.0) is now available, June 25th, 2014:

- p2 repository: p2 software repository: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4.
- p2 repository for Luna: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
- Eclipse with CDT: [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunar)

Use the "`Install New Software...`" dialog and entering the p2 repository URLs.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to "install new software". I guess I'll look it up.

Comment: @user3750687 it is in the "Help" menu: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-124.htm

Comment: It works! I though that the library was not included but I forgot the .cpp extension. Scratch that I have a new problem, std does not exist!!!

Comment: @user3750687 you need to have gcc installed (http://askubuntu.com/a/179616/5470) What OS are you on? See also http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL is supposed to be `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4/`.

`http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/luna` is an invalid link.

So to install CDT in Eclipse, just go to `Help > Install New Software...` and add `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4/` to your list of repositories.

Comment: I have fixed my link in my answer. It is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna: it includes everything.